# MVVM binding from static method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I'm working on my app that will get data from online database. I would like to show  progress bar. Problem is that I can not make it work.

Current situation is:

- I am using FreshMVVM.
- Method to get data form online is in class `FirebaseCloudNight`. There is static method `SynchronizeNights` with which I get all nights (with function `foreach`). I would like to show progress bar based on nights done/remaining to be synchronized.
- In `ViewModel` I have property `CurrentProgress` that is correctly bidden to View. I can not update this property correctly.
- I left out a lot of code because I think is irrelevant. If you need more code please let me know.
- The only solution I found is to create new instance of MV class. But after additional reading I found out that, although I see that property changed, binding was not OK, because it changed new instance of property.

Issue is that the only way I found is to update this property based on new instance. But then MVVM does not work --> UI is not refreshed because it updates different instance of property. How can this be done?

Below is my code (if it will be of any help).

Code to retrieve DB from cloud

> ```
> namespace iVanApp.Services {
> public class FirebaseCloudNight : FirebaseCloudBaseHelper
> {
>     
>     static public async Task<bool> SynchronizeNights()
>     {
>         // Synchronize from Cloud to DB
>         foreach (var cloudItem in cloudNights)
>         {
>             CurrentProgress= currentNight / numberOfNights;
>             try
>             { 
>                 //Here I removed code for retriving data from online DB
>                 currentNight ++;
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 return false;
>             }
>             return true;
>         }
>      }
>  }
> ```

ViewModel Code

> ```
>  async Task GetData()
>     {
>             bool success = await FirebaseCloudNight.SynchronizeNights();>                 
>     }
>
>     float currentProgress;
>     public float CurrentProgress
>     {
>         get => currentProgress;
>         set
>         {
>             currentProgress = value;
>             RaisePropertyChanged();
>         }
>     }
> ```

EDIT:
What I tried and does not work (because of obvious reasons)

> ```
> namespace iVanApp.Services {
> public class FirebaseCloudNight : FirebaseCloudBaseHelper
> {
>     
>     static public async Task<bool> SynchronizeNights()
>     {
>         // Synchronize from Cloud to DB
>         var VM = new UserAuthenticationPageModel();
>         foreach (var cloudItem in cloudNights)
>         {
>             VM.CurrentProgress = currentNight / numberOfNights;
>             try
>             { 
>                 //Here I removed code for retriving data from online DB
>                 currentNight ++;
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 return false;
>             }
>             return true;
>         }
>      }
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer that is working

Added code in ViewModel code behind

> ```
> public class UserAuthenticationPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
> {
>     public static UserAuthenticationPageModel Instance { get; private set; }
>     public UserAuthenticationPageModel()
>     {
>         Instance = this;
>     }
> ```

Modified code in `FirebaseCloudNight`

> ```
> namespace iVanApp.Services { public class FirebaseCloudNight :
> FirebaseCloudBaseHelper {
>
> static public async Task<bool> SynchronizeNights()
> {
>     // Synchronize from Cloud to DB
>     foreach (var cloudItem in cloudNights)
>     {
>         UserAuthenticationPageModel.Instance.CurrentProgress = currentNight / numberOfNights
>         try
>         { 
>             //Here I removed code for retriving data from online DB
>             currentNight ++;
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>         return true;
>     }
>  }  }
> ```